# running R in emacs on LSF

Tags: r, emacs, ess, lsf

I would like to run R in emacs using ESS. My R session runs interactively but is submitted to a different host using LSF. Is there a way to make this work? That is, R is not being run locally.  However, ESS seems to run a local copy which doesn't work since it limits the resources. Is there a place to specify what command ESS should run to launch R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESS can work with remote processes easily:

http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-processes-on-Remote-Computers

You need to connect to the remote host yourself using emacs's telnet or ssh, launch R there, then tell ESS to use this buffer by doing `M-x ess-remote` in that buffer.

Comment: yes i've seen this. that's not what i need though. i need emacs to issue the lsf command rather than me telneting to a remote node. so instead of emacs running "R" i need it to run "bsub R stuff"

Comment: I see. I think out of the box ESS supports batch processing for SAS and JAGS only. The JAGS implementation (ess-jags-d.el) is fairly simple, could you use it as starting point and modify it to accommodate submitting R jobs via lsf?

Comment: Can you use emacs shell and run an LSF interactive job as a substitute for ssh?  Something like "bsub -Is /bin/bash".

Comment: interesting idea @MichaelClosson, i'm a newbie so could you elaborate on how that would work.

Comment: How would you launch an interactive R session in your LSF configuration? "bsub -Is /your_path_to_R/R" could be one way. You can open shell in emacs with "M-x shell", then launch R via that bsub command, then do "M-x ess-remote" in that buffer. ess-remote does not care where the interactive R session comes from as long as it is running in some emacs buffer.

Comment: I've never used R before.  Alex Vorobiev's explanation is what I was thinking.